# UITextView Auto-Correction is causing DidEndEditing callback

Tags: ios, keyboard, textview, uitextview, spell-checking

I have a `UITextView` element in my custom cell with auto spell correction on. When I enter next word after spell correction on wrong text followed by a space and then clear it by pressing backspace, The delegate callback of `UITextView` `didEndEditing` receives causing keyboard to hide..
Why is this happening?? I haven't done nothing special in the code..
Is it the default behavior of spell correction that it sends end editing callback upon correction??

I have nothing implemented special in `shouldChangeTextInRange:` method.

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    return YES ;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `-textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` method, assuming you've implemented it?

Comment: I have added code for method "textView shouldChangeTextInRange:" in which I've nothing implemented and just returning YES.. Is it correct or should I implement something else here??

Answer (score 0):

Something is causing your `UITextView` to resign as first responder.  If you place a breakpoint in the `-didEndEditing` method and look at the stack trace (make it as verbose as possible by moving the slider to the far right), you should see the steps leading up to the callback.

I created a bare-bones app containing a `UITextView`, implemented the delegate methods and enabled autocorrection.  Following the steps you described, I did **not** see the same behavior.

Comment: What do you see in the stack trace if you place a breakpoint in `-didEndEditing`?